# HP P4500 G2 system board replacement

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, storage-area-network

Initially, I had such a problem: HP P4500 G2 does not turn on. So we buy new system board (spare 583736-001) and when i replace it storage start to power on, but with error code 1611 - Fan Solution Not Sufficient, Fan 4 missing and power off in 5 seconds. Storage have "Redundant Fan Configuration" - 4 pair of fans, i plug them to following connectors:

System fan 1/2 to J63 on the system board
System fan 3/4 to J71 on the system board
System fan 5/6 to J62 on the system board
System fan 7/8 to J68 on the system board

(From HP ProLiant DL180 G6 Server Maintenance and Service Guide)
I try different fans (i have some spare fans), clear nwram (System maintenance swich S6), to swap fans - nothing helps. Then i try to popolate fan connector #4 with additional single fan and storage can post (with fan 4 warning) and load os. But this is not the solution - I think that the problem is probably in the Jumper Setting, but i cant find and guide for HP P4500 G2 system board or matetials on HP Partner Services Media Library. I also think that it may be old BIOS firmware (10/14/2010), but firmware from DL180 G6 is unsuitable, and i can find special P4500 G2 BIOS.
Has anyone faced with a similar fan problem? Or may be someone have system board replacement guide?

Comment: Isn't your HP Lefthand SAN under support?

Comment: maybe your jumpers are not correct

Comment: The OP already mentioned jumpers.  Do you know the correct jumper settings for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

HP often ship refurbish. It happened to me in the past to got a defect part as a replacement. Return it as DOA.

As for the connection if you replaced and watched what you did they are no chance that you did a error at that level.